# Override css of bower package

Tags: angularjs, css, mean-stack

Hi i am using some bower packages but there are some css rule defined like below:

```
.rn-carousel-indicator {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
```

I want to override it into my common.css to remove the background-color, I can successfully set it as red but it cannot apply with none:

```
.rn-carousel-indicator {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Anyway I can do with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think `none` is a valid value for `background-color`. Try using `transparent` instead if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color):

> The background-color CSS property sets the background color of an element, either through a color value or the keyword transparent.

So `none` is invalid, you should use:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options

```
background: none;
```

or

```
background-color: initial;
```

Note, `initial` has some dodgy [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial). 
(No support in IE apparently)

Comment: ...and their probably both inferior to `background-color: transparent` that Clive suggested.

Answer (score 0):

background-color: none is invalid. you have to use background color transparent property.

For example:

```
background-color: transparent;
```